# Making OpenGL's int constants typesafe using type classes

Tags: scala, opengl

I'm tying to create a typesafe wrapper around lwjgl. Most importantly, I want it to be a compile time error to pass the wrong constants to a function, e.g. calling `glEnable(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER)`. This whould be rather easy if it weren't for different contexts supporting different constants for the same function.

I figured I'd use type classes to model which constants can be passed to which function. I've got a solution but admittedly it's a bit ugly and fails to apply a certain implicit:

```
trait GlConst { val glConst: Int }

trait GlConstCompanion[C <: GlConst] { val instance: C }


class GlDepthTest private () extends GlConst { val glConst = GL_DEPTH_TEST }

object GlDepthTest extends GlConstCompanion[GlDepthTest] {
  val instance = new GlDepthTest
}


class GlLineSmooth private () extends GlConst { val glConst = GL_LINE_SMOOTH }

object GlLineSmooth extends GlConstCompanion[GlLineSmooth] {
  val instance = new GlLineSmooth
}


class GlArrayBuffer private () extends GlConst { val glConst = GL_ARRAY_BUFFER }

object GlArrayBuffer extends GlConstCompanion[GlArrayBuffer] {
  val instance = new GlArrayBuffer
}


// type class for arguments to glEnable
trait GlEnableCap[T <: GlConst] extends GlConst


object GlContext33 {
  implicit object GlDepthTestIsEnableCap extends GlEnableCap[GlDepthTest] {
    val glConst = GlDepthTest.instance.glConst
  }

  implicit object GlLineSmoothIsEnableCap extends GlEnableCap[GlLineSmooth] {
    val glConst = GlLineSmooth.instance.glConst
  }

  def glEnable[T <: GlConst : GlEnableCap](t: T): Unit = println(implicitly[GlEnableCap[T]].glConst)
}

object Test extends App {
  import GlContext33._

  implicit def constComp2Const[C <: GlConst](cc: GlConstCompanion[C]): C = cc.instance

  // works
  glEnable(GlDepthTest.instance)

  // fails to apply implicit glConstComp2Comp
  glEnable(GlDepthTest)

  // fails intentionally
  glEnable(GlArrayBuffer)
}
```

Is there a way to get the implicit to work? Or is there an even better way to wrap OpenGL's constants?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a rule of thumb, don't use `implicit`s if you don't have to.
In this case you can solve it just as well using only type bounds:

```scala
// Start writing your ScalaFiddle code here

val GL_DEPTH_TEST = 1
val GL_LINE_SMOOTH = 1
val GL_ARRAY_BUFFER = 1


trait GlConstCap

trait GlEnableConstCap extends GlConstCap
trait GlBufferConstCap extends GlConstCap

trait GlConst[C <: GlConstCap] { val value: Int }

object GlDepthTest extends GlConst[GlEnableConstCap] {
  val value = GL_DEPTH_TEST
}

object GlLineSmooth extends GlConst[GlEnableConstCap] {
  val value = GL_LINE_SMOOTH
}

object GlArrayBuffer extends GlConst[GlBufferConstCap] {
  val value = GL_ARRAY_BUFFER
}


object GlContext33 {
  def glEnable[T <: GlConst[GlEnableConstCap]](t: T): Unit = println(t.value)
}

object Test extends App {
  import GlContext33._

  // works
  glEnable(GlDepthTest)

  // fails to apply implicit glConstComp2Comp
  glEnable(GlDepthTest)

  // fails intentionally
  glEnable(GlArrayBuffer)
}
```

[Try it out!](https://scalafiddle.io/sf/e2AlP3R/3)

Note: You might want to add contravariance to `C` in `GlConst` if you want to create deeper inheritance structures of `GlConstCap`.

---

I hope this helps.